# Display problem in HP Compaq laptop

Tags: drivers, display

I am recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 in my laptop HP Compaq with an AMD Turion processor.Model no. HP presario V6000. It works well when booted from DVD but after installation display will not work and notification comes saying that paid drivers are avilable for downloading. But it does not give any detailes and I can not explore it because there is no display. Please advice me how to procewed.
Sachidananda

Answer (score 0):

That notification says something about `Proprietary Drivers` not `paid`.

Anyway open the Dash and type `Software and Updates`. Another way is to open Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type `gksu software-properties-gtk` then hit Enter.

Once it opens select the last tab `Additional Drivers`. You should see there the drivers available for your PC. Select one of the tested ones and click `Apply Changes`.

Another way to install graphics drivers is from terminal:

If you have NVidia:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

If you have ATI:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

After installation it would be a good idea to restart, or at least log out and back in.